# Calculating with multi arrays

Tags: php

I need help with some of my code. I need to use the numbers in `prijs` for a calculation.

```
$autos = array(
    "<b>Mercedes</b>" =>array(
    "Kenteken" => "77NLXJ",
    "Prijs"    => "54800",
),
    "<b>Tesla</b>"    =>array(
    "Kenteken" => "GV713G",
    "Prijs"    => "70700",
),
    "<b>Porsche</b>"  =>array(
    "Kenteken" => "GG101K",
    "Prijs"    => "85000",
)
```

Is this possible?

```php
  $keys = array_keys($autos);
  for($i = 0; $i < count($autos); $i++) {
    echo $keys[$i] . "<br>";
    foreach($autos[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: *Is this possible* - yes.  Not sure what calculation you want to do or where the problem is though.

Comment: What kind of calculation are you willing to do? If you just want to get the total sum of this index, you can do something like this: `array_sum(array_column($array, 'Prijs'));` `array_column` will get all **Prijis** indexes in your array and `array_sum` will sum all of the **Prijis** indexes.

array_sum: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php &
array_column: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access and change them, you need to access them through the `$autos` array:

```
//by loop:
foreach($autos as $key => $auto){
    //get or set them with this var
    $autos[$key]["Prijs"];
}

//to get and set them directly:
$autos[0]["Prijs"];
$autos[1]["Prijs"];
$autos[2]["Prijs"];
```

Comment: This is not giving me the results just an error. (Undefined Offset)

Comment: @WouterWent that's how you access the variables. You need to write an expression with them, e.g. `$autos[0]["Prijs"] = 33 * 2`